# Any Software to convert float to any-precision FPU? [or Matlab solution]

Tags: matlab, vhdl, fpu

I want to convert a lot of float numbers to multiple-precision FPU like '0x4049000000.....', perform calculations, change the precision and then again perform calculations and so on...

I know the theory as [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_unit) but I want a Software, Online tool or Matlab solution to convert 6000+ numbers to FPU format (like IEEE single precision) in 0.0 ~ 51.0 range.

Any Suggestions?

Note: I need custom precision where I can describe number of digits of Mentissa and Exponent.

**EDIT**: It is also called Radix-Independent Floating-Point as described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_854-1987) and [here](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=27840)

**2nd EDIT**: [IEEE single precision convert](http://www.binaryconvert.com/convert_float.html) and [IEEE double Precision convert](http://www.binaryconvert.com/convert_double.html)  are examples. You enter any float number e.g. 3.1454, you will get its IEEE (single or double precision) float value in binary/hex. @rick

Comment: Use the floating point library, standard in VHDL-2008.

Comment: can this library convert between standard float to FPU? @BrianDrummond

Comment: What does this have to do with MATLAB?

Comment: Matlab has num2hex() command which converts to double precision. It may have some command to specify other precisions, I thought, @rayryeng

Comment: Could you please add a couple examples with the inputs and corresponding output values? It can almost surely be done with float_pkg in VHDL, but I'd need an example to understand exactly how.

Comment: I have added the explanation in question **2nd EDIT** for you. @rick

Comment: Thanks, I think I didn't state clearly what I was thinking, I meant a numeric example (input value -> transformation -> output value).

Comment: **Input**:- `49.0215463456`
**Output**:- `0x404882C207D8D9A4` [its IEEE double precision, I need IEEE quadruple precision or anything in between]. @rick

Answer (score 1):

A quick look at the VHDL-2008 floating point library `float_pkg` shows that it instantiates a generic package with generic parameters set to match IEEE single precision floats.

`package float_pkg is new IEEE.float_generic_pkg (...)`

You should find this library as part of your simulator installation, wherever you usually look for the standard libraries such as `numeric_std`. On my system it is at `/opt/ghdl-0.32/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.2/vhdl/src/ieee2008/float_pkg.vhdl` - if you can't find it on your system, it's available online, search for "VHDL 2008 float package" ought to get you there.

You can instantiate this generic package (using `float_pkg` as an example) for any precision you like (within reasonable limits).

A quick look at `IEEE.float_generic_pkg` shows that it declares functions `to_float` and `to_real`, I'd like to think they have the obvious behaviour.

So the answer is ... yes.

```
  -- real to float
  function to_float (
    arg                  : REAL;
    size_res             : UNRESOLVED_float;
    constant round_style : round_type := float_round_style;  -- rounding option
    constant denormalize : BOOLEAN    := float_denormalize)  -- Use IEEE extended FP
    return UNRESOLVED_float;
```

and

```
  -- float to real
  function to_real (
    arg                  : UNRESOLVED_float;  -- floating point input
    constant check_error : BOOLEAN    := float_check_error;  -- check for errors
    constant denormalize : BOOLEAN    := float_denormalize)  -- Use IEEE extended FP
    return REAL;
```

Comment: Still I dont know how to use it to do my work...! you made a nice effort but I am not getting the benefit. Can you tell me how to convert a float number to any-precision float with this? A small Example?

Comment: so what have you tried and where did you get stuck?

Comment: Okay. Let me state my position. I am doing my FYP to implement an oceanic model on FPGA in Verilog. I have done it but it is not Area efficient. Now I need to do it using Flopoco [an fpu arithmatic code generator in vhdl]. I have learned Verilog somehow but I am naive to VHDL. Thats why I am not getting what you said in the answer...

Answer (score 1):

`float_pkg` should be all you need. It gives you some predefined floating-point types (e.g., IEEE single and double precision), plus the ability to define custom floating-point values with arbitrary number of bits for the fraction and the exponent.

Based on your numeric example, here is some code to convert from a `real` value to single, double, and quadruple precision floats.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.float_pkg.all;

entity floating_point_demo is
end;

architecture example of floating_point_demo is
begin
    process
        variable real_input_value: real := 49.0215463456;
        variable single_precision_float: float32;
        variable double_precision_float: float64;
        variable quadruple_precision_float: float128;
    begin
        single_precision_float := to_float(real_input_value, single_precision_float);
        report to_string(single_precision_float);
        report to_hstring(single_precision_float);

        double_precision_float := to_float(real_input_value, double_precision_float);
        report to_string(double_precision_float);
        report to_hstring(double_precision_float);

        quadruple_precision_float := to_float(real_input_value, quadruple_precision_float);
        report to_string(quadruple_precision_float);
        report to_hstring(quadruple_precision_float);

        wait;
    end process;
end;
```

The example above uses types `float32`, `float64`, and `float128` from `float_pkg`. However, you can achieve the same effect using objects of type `float`, whose size can be defined at their declarations:

```
variable single_precision_float: float(8 downto -23);
variable double_precision_float: float(11 downto -52);
variable quadruple_precision_float: float(15 downto -112);
```

To convert from a `float` to a `real` value, you can use the `to_real()` function:

```
-- To print the real value of a float object:
report to_string(to_real(quadruple_precision_float));

-- To convert from a float and assign to a real:
real_value := to_real(quadruple_precision_float);
```

Comment: Thanks. But I am stuck at adding library. I have tried like in this link but not helped http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx14_1/ise_c_working_with_vhdl_libraries.htm.

Comment: You may have to use the compatibility floating-point packages if your synthesis tool is not compatible with VHDL-2008: [www.eda.org/fphdl](http://www.eda.org/fphdl)

Comment: I have the library files float_pkg.vhd in these directories. http://img42.com/RntS2. I included them from Project => New Vhdl Library in ISE but its not working. I does not recognize the library functions used in main code.